# Animation Starts when touch and Stops when UnTouched

Tags: java, android, animation

So my question is how can I make an animation Starts when touch and Once it's not Touched it plays another animation .. 
(sorry for my English..)

main.java :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView is = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        is.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.animup);
        final AnimationDrawable animup = (AnimationDrawable) is.getBackground();
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.anim);  
        final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
        is.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {



                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
                        anim.setVisible(true, true);
                        anim.start();

                        //perform your animation when button is touched and held
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        anim.setVisible(true, true);
                        animup.start();

                        //perform your animation when button is released
                    }
                    return false;




                }
            });

    };

    ;
  }
```

+Another Problem......
**EDITED**

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();anim.setVisible(true, true);
anim.start();
but it's making one animation works only , not both !

Comment: [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18803805/edit) and add your code to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) will help you.

**Edit**

For implementing touch and release you have to use `onTouchListener` rather than `onClickListener`.

Below is the code-

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //perform your animation when button is touched and held
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          //perform your animation when button is released
        }
    }
};
```

**Edit 2**

In the `else if` block you are not setting the visibility of `anim` to false. I feel that is the problem. Rewrite your code as this-

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            anim.setVisible(true,true);
            anim.start();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
         anim.stop(); //perform your animation when button is released
         animup.setVisible(true,true);
         animup.start();
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: I need it to start an animation when I hold the button, and start another animation after I leave it

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) , but now i hacve another problem in this code you gave me, when i Put anim.start under if event .. it turns red !! as it doesn't exist.

Comment: what do you mean by it turns red? Please explain the problem. I am not getting you.

Comment: Where have you defined and declared anim?

Comment: iv.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.anim);

Comment: Ok i've edited the code now, but the problem now is the 2nd Animation which is "animup" is not working but the 1st one "anim" is working.